# Should I override the default ExecutionContext?

Tags: scala, concurrency

When using futures in scala the default behaviour is to use the default Implicits.global execution context.  It seems this defaults to making one thread available per processor.  In a more traditional threaded web application this seems like a poor default when the futures are performing a task such as waiting on a database (as opposed to some cpu bound task).

I'd expect that overriding the default context would be fairly standard in production but I can find so little documentation about doing it that it seems that it might not be that common.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Instead of thinking of it as overriding the default execution context, why not ask instead "Should I use multiple execution contexts for different things?"  If that's the question, then my answer would be yes. Where I work, we use Akka. Within our app, we use the default Akka execution context for non blocking functionality.  Then, because there is no good non blocking jdbc driver currently, all of our blocking SQL calls use a separate execution context, where we have a thread per connection approach. Keeping the main execution context (a fork join pool) free from blocking lead to a significant increase in throughput for us.

I think it's perfectly ok to use multiple different execution contexts for different types of work within your system.  It's worked well for us.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that the important decision factor is whether or not you use blocking (or long runing) code in futures. If you don't, using separate execution contexts is actually counter productive.

Comment: If you want a custom executor you can control but would like to stick with the default parallelism and other parameters, it seems that `ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(new scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool)` (without parameters) seems to do the trick; creates a pool of 8 on my i7 with 8 cores (incl. hyperthreading), which matches what `ForkJoinPool.commonPool` contains.

Comment: @cmbaxter do you wrap your JDBC calls in `blocking {}` inside the futures? Is it necessary if there is a separated ExecutionContext?

Comment: @IvanYurchenko, I do, but I'm not actually 100% sure it's necessary.  In my model, in which I use Akka, I use a PinnedDispatcher for each actor in a pool that is wrapping a connection.  Given each connection basically has it's own dedicated thread, I'm not sure it's necessary in this scenario.  I need to profile it at some point to see if it's helping, hurting, or doing nothing.  Now, for other situations, using `blocking{}` might be a good idea, so I guess it depends on the situation.

Comment: @cmbaxter, do you mind sharing the Akka configuration you used to achieve one thread per connection?

Comment: It's more than config. We had to write an actor that wrapped the connection and then setup a pool of those and then assigned a pinned dispatcher to that pool. The pinned dispatcher is the key to getting the thread per actor and thus in this case per connection behavior.

Answer (score 3):

The "correct" answer is that your methods that needs to use an ExecutionContext require an ExecutionContext in their signature, so you can supply ExecutionContext(s) from the "outside" to control execution at a higher level.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, creating and using other execution contexts in you application is definitely a good idea.

Execution contexts will modularize your concurrency model and isolate the different parts of your application, so that if something goes wrong in a part of your app, the other parts will be less impacted by this. To consider your example, you would have a different execution context for DB-specific operations and another one for say, processing of web requests.

In [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/jboner/scalability-availability-stability-patterns) by Jonas Boner this pattern is referred to as creating "Bulkheads" in your application for greater stability & fault tolerance.

I must admit I haven't heard much about execution context usage by itself. However, I do see this principle applied in some frameworks. For example, Play will use different execution contexts for different types of jobs and they encourage you to split your tasks into different pools if necessary: [Play Thread Pools](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ThreadPools)

The Akka middleware also suggests splitting your app into different contexts for the different concurrency zones in your application. They use the concept of [Dispatcher](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/scala/dispatchers.html) which is an execution context on batteries.

Also, most operators in the scala concurrency library require an execution context. This is by design to give you the flexibility you need when in modularizing your application concurrency-wise.

Comment: The default `ExecutionContext` in Scala is the most recent ForkJoin pool. Given that, your statement that the global execution context "is there for small, quick jobs but it will certainly not scale to a larger application" is unfounded.

Comment: It's not that the default execution context is not performant in itself. I meant to say that using only one execution context in a large scale application is not the best thing. Nonetheless, I removed that comment since it was confusing.