# Slick Database Sessions, Efficiency, and Threading in Akka

Tags: scala, akka, slick

I am currently working with a very large database (>50GB) and trying to understand the most efficient, usable approach that plays well with Akka's inherent threading.

Regarding the "wrapping everything inside withSession{ }" approach, while this would be an easier fix, I am concerned that this would restrict Akka's threading between actors. I am not that knowledgeable on how Akka's threading works, and how wrapping an entire actor system inside of withSession would effect it.

Another approach is to call withSession whenever the database is accessed, which is too inefficient. The "withSession {" code segment takes ~6ms to execute, and we are making millions of queries.

Essentially: what is the best way to rapidly access a database with Slick and Akka without breaking threading?

I have heard of approaches using implicit sessions and transactions, but I am struggling to find documentation on either of these.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16834855/406435) to get some advices.

Comment: How exactly can you interface an ExecutionContext with Sessions?

Or would the best solution be to simply put all database accessing code under a different ExecutionContext than the rest?

Comment: You could create N actors, each with its own session. Each actor should use its own session and all communication with database should be passed through this bunch of actors.

Comment: one approach might be to use withSession on demand in combination with a Connection pool to reduce acquisition overhead. see e.g. http://fernandezpablo85.github.io/2013/04/07/slick_connection_pooling.html (i'm the author of that connection pool, so i gravitate to it. in theory, in an akka world, there should be clever solutions with actor-managed connections. but maintaining long-lived, reusable cxns is nontrivial in practice. existing pools do it. ymmv!)

Comment: Watch out for the slick-extension licensing needed for Oracle, MS SQL etc. It's very expensive!! I would avoid slick unless I knew my app would never need to go onto enterprise rdbms.

Comment: +1 for pooling per @SteveWaldman . The connection pool removes the significant cost of creating and taking down the connections - and can be done transparently to the rest of the app that just sees the withSession and do not care the underlying Connections are already available

Comment: This provide a reading and writing pools to be used with slick. https://github.com/privateblue/asyncpools

Answer (score 4):

Better late than never:

The recommended way is using a jdbc connection pool (e.g. c3p0). You need to make sure a session is acquired and returned from and in between kept on the same thread. `withSession` lazily acquires a connection from the pool and returns it at the end of the scope. Quickly acquire connections when you need them and return them to the pool immediately after.